# How to use Datastax java driver for knowing a node is down in the Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

How can we use Datastax Java Driver to know down nodes in Cassandra Cluster? Does metadata of driver is updated continuously or do we have to register any listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver consumes gossip info with the cluster.  If a node is down, it’ll know it and not route traffic to it.  No worries about engineering anything to do it yourself.